# How to convert string to Json/maps

Tags: java, json, maps

I want to convert below string to either json or maps to read individual messages, so how can I achieve that.

```
 {
  "import_set"XXXX00123",
  "staging_table": "u_xx_imp_set_xxx_yyy",
  "result": [
    {
      "transform_map": "EE Trsfrm test ",
      "status": "error",
      "error_message": "Unable to resolve ",
      "status_message": "Unable to resolve target record"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here I want to read `status`, `error_message` etc.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectMapper or Gson. ObjectMapper code to parse the string into a Map:

```
private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> map = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue("jsonString",
            new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {})
```

Gson code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, Object> myMap = gson.fromJson("jsonString", 
  new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a plenty of libraries that allow you to parse JSON. Probably, the most popular two are [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) and [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). Here are the examples of parsing a string into a JSON node with them.

**Gson**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    final JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse("{ \"import_set\": \"ISET0010118\", \"staging_table\": \"u_ee_imp_set_asset_nmi\", " +
                                               "\"result\": [{ \"transform_map\": \"EE Trsfrm Map Asset NMI \", \"status\": " +
                                               "\"error\", \"error_message\": \"Unable to resolve target record, coalesce values not " +
                                               "present: u_assetid; Invalid table \", \"status_message\": \"Unable to resolve target " +
                                               "record, coalesce values not present: u_assetid\" }] }").getAsJsonObject();

    System.out.println(jsonObject);
    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("result").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("status").getAsString());
    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("result").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("error_message").getAsString());
}
```

**Jackson**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree("{ \"import_set\": \"ISET0010118\", \"staging_table\": \"u_ee_imp_set_asset_nmi\", " +
                                              "\"result\": [{ " +
                                              "\"transform_map\": \"EE Trsfrm Map Asset NMI \", \"status\": \"error\", " +
                                              "\"error_message\": \"Unable to resolve " +
                                              "target record, coalesce values not present: u_assetid; Invalid table \", " +
                                              "\"status_message\": \"Unable to resolve" +
                                              " target record, coalesce values not present: u_assetid\" }] }");

    System.out.println(jsonNode);
    System.out.println(jsonNode.get("result").get(0).get("status").asText());
    System.out.println(jsonNode.get("result").get(0).get("error_message").asText());
}
```

Both examples will print:

```
{"import_set":"ISET0010118","staging_table":"u_ee_imp_set_asset_nmi","result":[{"transform_map":"EE Trsfrm Map Asset NMI ","status":"error","error_message":"Unable to resolve target record, coalesce values not present: u_assetid; Invalid table ","status_message":"Unable to resolve target record, coalesce values not present: u_assetid"}]}
error
Unable to resolve target record, coalesce values not present: u_assetid; Invalid table
```

Or you can create a POJO to host your data and parse string right into objests:

**Gson**

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        final Results results = gson.fromJson("{ \"import_set\": \"ISET0010118\", \"staging_table\": \"u_ee_imp_set_asset_nmi\", " +
                                              "\"result\": [{ " +
                                              "\"transform_map\": \"EE Trsfrm Map Asset NMI \", \"status\": \"error\", " +
                                              "\"error_message\": \"Unable to resolve " +
                                              "target record, coalesce values not present: u_assetid; Invalid table \", " +
                                              "\"status_message\": \"Unable to resolve" +
                                              " target record, coalesce values not present: u_assetid\" }] }", Results.class);

        System.out.println(results.getResult().get(0).getStatus());
        System.out.println(results.getResult().get(0).getErrorMessage());
    }
}

class Results {
    @SerializedName("import_set")
    private String importSet;
    @SerializedName("staging_table")
    private String stagingTable;
    @SerializedName("result")
    private List<Result> result;

    public String getImportSet() {
        return importSet;
    }

    public void setImportSet(String importSet) {
        this.importSet = importSet;
    }

    public String getStagingTable() {
        return stagingTable;
    }

    public void setStagingTable(String stagingTable) {
        this.stagingTable = stagingTable;
    }

    public List<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}

class Result {
    @SerializedName("transform_map")
    private String transformMap;
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("error_message")
    private String errorMessage;
    @SerializedName("status_message")
    private String statusMessage;

    public String getTransformMap() {
        return transformMap;
    }

    public void setTransformMap(String transformMap) {
        this.transformMap = transformMap;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public String getStatusMessage() {
        return statusMessage;
    }

    public void setStatusMessage(String statusMessage) {
        this.statusMessage = statusMessage;
    }
}
```

**Jackson**

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final Results results = mapper.readValue("{ \"import_set\": \"ISET0010118\", \"staging_table\": \"u_ee_imp_set_asset_nmi\", " +
                                                 "\"result\": [{ " +
                                                 "\"transform_map\": \"EE Trsfrm Map Asset NMI \", \"status\": \"error\", " +
                                                 "\"error_message\": \"Unable to resolve " +
                                                 "target record, coalesce values not present: u_assetid; Invalid table \", " +
                                                 "\"status_message\": \"Unable to resolve" +
                                                 " target record, coalesce values not present: u_assetid\" }] }", Results.class);

        System.out.println(results.getResult().get(0).getStatus());
        System.out.println(results.getResult().get(0).getErrorMessage());
    }
}

class Results {
    @JsonProperty("import_set")
    private String importSet;
    @JsonProperty("staging_table")
    private String stagingTable;
    @JsonProperty("result")
    private List<Result> result;

    public String getImportSet() {
        return importSet;
    }

    public void setImportSet(String importSet) {
        this.importSet = importSet;
    }

    public String getStagingTable() {
        return stagingTable;
    }

    public void setStagingTable(String stagingTable) {
        this.stagingTable = stagingTable;
    }

    public List<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}

class Result {
    @JsonProperty("transform_map")
    private String transformMap;
    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty("error_message")
    private String errorMessage;
    @JsonProperty("status_message")
    private String statusMessage;

    public String getTransformMap() {
        return transformMap;
    }

    public void setTransformMap(String transformMap) {
        this.transformMap = transformMap;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public String getStatusMessage() {
        return statusMessage;
    }

    public void setStatusMessage(String statusMessage) {
        this.statusMessage = statusMessage;
    }
}
```

As you see, Gson and Jackson are pretty similar and differs mostly in annotation and method names, but the principles are the same.

Comment: Thanks @madhead , I tried with jackson and it' working.